# Obtaining one value for each individual from a correlation

Tags: correlation

Currently I am thinking about how to use a correlation between two parameters for further analysis.

Specifically, I have data on body size as well as data on a behavior. The data are strongly two-tailed (some individuals do almost nothing whereas other individuals do a lot) and thus deviates strongly from normality.
Now, in some treatments, there is a significant (Spearman) correlation between those two, whereas in other treatments there is not.
As a next step, I would like to calculate heritability of this size-dependent behavior (I have obtained the same data from the parents as well), but for this purpose I need a single datapoint for each individual. I have been thinking about using the residuals from the Spearman correlation for each treatment but this would be inappropriate for the cases where there is no correlation; also, a Spearman correlation is unsuitable for this as the data is just ordered by size. Alternatively, I could attempt to do a Pearson correlation over the whole dataset, but this is inappropriate as well as the data is not normally distributed. Does any of you have a suggestion for how to obtain such data from my dataset?

edit: I have had an idea: How about dividing the behavioral data through size?

Thanks!
Cheers
Anso